# Difference between REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO and REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I read the developer docs on how to use existing Camera software on the device to take a picture and return to the app [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) and I was confused by the fact that when simply grabbing a thumbnail, they use the following intent code

```
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

however, when taking a picture and saving the full file, they use:

```
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

At least for me, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO can not be resolved, and I cant find any reference to it anywhere. Anyone know what the differences are between the two?

Comment: as CommonsWare stated, they declarated those both fields at the beginn of Activity and assigned to them the same value(**1**). The changed the name in order to show that they introduce new topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO can not be resolved

While they have a typo in their source, they [do show where they define that integer](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath). Scroll down to the last code snippet in the "Save the Full-Size Photo" section.

> Anyone know what the differences are between the two?

In the code presented on that page, there is no difference between the two, as they are both defined to be `1`. This is sloppy example. :-(

In general, if one activity calls `startActivityForResult()` for two or more distinct requests, you will want to use different numeric values for the `requestCode`. Both results will be delivered to the same `onActivityResult()` method implementation, and you use the `requestCode` to distinguish one result from another.

Comment: Great, thanks! Failed to register the integer definition there, makes sense.